# Order got deleted automatically after successful payment

Tags: magento2.3.3

I am using `Magento 2.3.3`.

One order was automatically deleted after successful payment via `authorize.net`.

I didn't found order in database in **quote** table in `reserve_order_id` column and also not in **sales_order** table.

I also got confirmation email too.

Is anyone knows why this happened?

And I am using the `mage-mojo` server and `mage-mojo` told me request header was too large.

but I want to know that if the request header was large than why payment was successful and why order email was received ?

I have 1 observer

**events.xml**

```
<event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
    <observer name="add_terracycle_option_to_order" instance="Vendor\Modulename\Observer\Terracycle" />
</event>
```

**Terracycle.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Terracycle implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $_cart;
    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cart,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }
    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $quoteRepository = $this->_cart;
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
        $terracycle_value = $quote->getTerracycle();
        $order->setTerracycle($terracycle_value);
        $order->save();
        $message = "Order Id: " . $order->getId() . " | terracycle_value: " . $terracycle_value;
        $this->_logger->info($message);  //saved in var/log/system.log
    }
}
```

Is this possible to have some fault with this code ? because as I test this code it is working fine.

Comment: Can you check is there any such action defined in observers of all your custom modules. For example sales_order_place_after observer

Comment: @AjwadSyed yes i already checked observers too. there is nothing with sales_order_place_after. but let me take a look once again for make sure.

Comment: @AjwadSyed there is one observer which saves 1 custom value in order.

Comment: @AjwadSyed please check i added code in question

Comment: All order are deleting after successful payment or some time, if every time orders are getting delete then first check by disabling all custom modules and see by creating order again.

Comment: @AjwadSyed it happened only once in entire life of the Magento store. it is running from 1 year. near about to 300 to 400 orders were placed

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me , random couple of orders are deleted , it send email , success payment and all working , but missing in all table and admin and customer too

Answer (score 0):

Persistance Cart issue

Got issue , try following steps to reproduce issue

1) enable persistence cart
2) login as customer and add product to cart and go to checkout page , don't complete checkout , just logout with product in cart
3) now you are logged out as customer but add same product as Guest user go to checkout in same browser , use different email and all different address details and complete order with any payment method , check money order will also work
4) now check order number , missing order number in admin , but your both email (customer email and guestemail ) have success orderemail , and one of that order is missing in admin panel and everywhere in DB , but found mixed data in Quote table

Issue is , persistence cart data is mixed from previous persistence cart data 
Temporary Solution 
Disable Persistence Cart

I have check open issue in https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13229